# Apache+php in docker. Cannot access ENV variables

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables

Im launching my docker image like this:

```
docker run -d \
--restart=always \
--name=site-$port \
-p $port:80 \
-v $PWD/..:/var/www/some-site:rw \
-e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
-t somename/ubuntu-1804
```

My php application cannot access `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` variable for some reason.
I get empty response when I try this:

```
echo getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');
```

However when I try to output all variables as root -I can see AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY defined with correct value:

```
docker exec -it myContainer bash
env
```

Why cannot I see passed ENV variable in PHP?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to export your environment variables so that the shell PHP is using has access to them